# Loading the API data into Picker in react native(Function component used)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, picker

I want to display the year data into the Picker. I am getting the error as "undefined".
This is the code I have done so far. .

```
const ShowAtt = (props) => {
  const [year, setYear] =  useState([]);

const yearApi = ()=>{
    fetch('url')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result=>{
        setYear(result.data);
        console.log(result.data);
        
    }).catch(err=>{
       
    })
}
<Picker style={{borderBottomColor:"black"}}
                    selectedValue={year}
                    onValueChange={newvSuburb => setYear(newvSuburb)} >
        
                    {year.map((item, key)=>(
                        <Picker.Item style={styles.input} 
                        label = {'${item.year}'} 
                        value = {'${item.year}'}
                        key={key} />)
                    )}
            
        </Picker>
```

This is the data obtained as a response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "year": 2020
        },
        {
            "year": 2021
        },

    ]
}
       
Error obtained is: Undefined is not a function(near '..year.. map .. .')
```

Answer (score 0):

the object {newvSuburb} how you defined in top?

```js
const ShowAtt = (props) => {
  const [year, setYear] =  useState([]);

const yearApi = ()=>{
    fetch('http://192.168.43.114:8000/api/years/')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result=>{
       // setYear(result.data);
  /* newvSuburb data here
*/
        console.log(result.data);
        
    }).catch(err=>{
       
    })
}
<Picker style={{borderBottomColor:"black"}}
                    selectedValue={year}
                    onValueChange={newvSuburb => setYear(newvSuburb)} >
        
                    {newvSuburb && newvSuburb.map((item, key)=>(
                        <Picker.Item style={styles.input} 
                        label = {'${item.year}'} 
                        value = {'${item.year}'}
                        key={key} />)
                    )}
            
        </Picker>
```

Comment: Do you mean whether i defined newvSuburb in the top?

Comment: so this fetch api is for list of years right?So the newvSuburb should be your data that return from api right? so maybe dun need setYear to your result data and set data as newvSuburb